# Is there any benefit to pre-purchasing Heart of the Swarm?

Tags: starcraft-2

Recently, I received an email from Blizzard offering me to pre-purchase Heart of the Swarm expansion to StarCraft 2: Wings of Liberty. Is there any benefit to pre-purchasing as opposed to buying it after it's released?

Comment: Hello, Ansis, and welcome to gaming! Unfortunately, questions about shopping suggestions and recommendations are considered off-topic for our site. As such, I've altered your question a bit (though if you want to discuss the relative pros/cons, you can surely join us in [chat]!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was wandering around Arqade Meta and found [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5539):

> This is currently the case for Starcraft 2 HOTS. Everybody can preorder on Amazon and get a free Beta key.

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, if you buy/upgrade a digital version through battle.net you can immediately download the beta client and start playing as per this link: https://eu.battle.net/support/en/blog/6816949

As far as I know, the beta is open until March 1st.